# Chrome rendering html/css differently on webserver vs locally

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have a strange problem with Chrome rendering a simple menu written in css and html. When I check the website on localhost everything works well but on a web server there is a bug.

Here is a link for the test website http://slitest.me.pn/menu_bug/ (saving it locally removes the bug)

I only care about chrome here. I have discovered that problem is caused by

```
 float: left;
```

in

```
 .menu li span
```

But what is funny, in chrome page inspector I manually disabled and enabled this parameter and everything started working fine, but after refreshing the page it is wrong again... no idea what is happening.

Here's the results I'm getting (localhost is what I assume to be correct):

[image: localhost vs webserver]

Comment: Could you specify what the bug is doing to your menu?

Comment: have you tried removing the float and just using margin-bottom: for the <span> elements to give them some space?

Comment: Maybe your style.css is cached? Try changing the CSS link to style.css?123

Comment: Internet explorer comes up the same as chrome on my machine, removing the float left puts a space in the menu. Is that the bug ? Could you explain the bug you want to get rid of to make it clearer for everybody here.

Comment: I'll post two screenshots in a moment.

Comment: Updated the question with an image.

Comment: when looking at the link you provided, I see what you see in your localhost, I suggest you make sure you are not having a caching issue..

Comment: @andy What chrome version?

Comment: @andy once I tried it at home it also was like the localhost version, but once I did one Ctrl-Shift-R it switched to the broken one and stays like that :/. It's driving me crazy.

Answer (score -3):

Try to use `margin-left` instead of `float:left`